# switch preference to send an sms in code

Tags: android, switch-statement, sharedpreferences, preferences

I need some help with an android project I am working on. I am trying to use switch preferences to send a certain text. Basically, it the user switches the switch from off to on, I want the phone to send a text saying "on". Then when the user turns the switch from on to off, it sends a text saying "off". All I need is to be able to see what the current state of the switch is and then if it's off, call a "turn on" method and vice-versa.

I've never asked a question like this, so I don't really know what part of my code to post.(If asked, I can post most of my code.) I think it has something to do with the onPreferenceChangeListener, but I'm not sure how to implement it. Any ideas?

Edit: Here is the main activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

public static final String KEY_ROOM1_SWITCH = "switch_room_1";

private SwitchPreference mSwitchPreference1;

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
//This is a sample of one of 4 switches that are being used. They are all basically the same, but with different variables
    if (key.equals(KEY_ROOM1_SWITCH)) {
        boolean checkedornot1;
        SharedPreferences myPreference=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        checkedornot1 = myPreference.getBoolean("switch_room_1", false);
        if (checkedornot1 = true)
        mSwitchPreference1.setChecked(true);
        else
        mSwitchPreference1.setChecked(false);
    }
  }
}
```

Do I need to grab the value that is stored in the shared preferences and make my choice based on that? or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Posting that code would be a good idea. Trying something (as you seem to have done) is better than asking people to do it for you. Even if your implementation is bad, you'll still learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Edit your class that extends PreferenceActivity and add the private variable: `private OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;`
2. Create and register your listener within the `onResume` method:

   ```
     public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
     listener = new OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
       public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sp, String key) {
         if (key.contains("your switchpreference key name")
         if (sp.getBoolean("your switchpreference key name",false) {
           sendOnSMS();
         } else {
           sendOffSMS();
         }
     }
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
   }
   ```
3. Unregister your listener within the `onPause` method:

   ```
   public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
   }
   ```
4. Implement the `sendOnSMS` and `sendOffSMS` methods.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great. I had a few problems but was able to fix them myself. Thanks again for the massive amount of work you just saved me.